# Use SSD from old laptop on new laptop as VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

My old HP laptop has an SSD (windows 7). I now have a new laptop (win 11 pro). I would like to access the data from the old laptop. Ideally I want to pull out the SSD, stick it in some sort of housing, then attach it to my new laptop and be able to get to the files but also to run it as a VM so I can get to things such as passwords etc.

Complete newbie at this sort of thing, but I am familiar with Windows etc.

Comment: Windows will auto-mount the partitions once you connect the old SSD via USB. Since you have a Pro version of Windows, for the VM, create a VM in Hyper-V _(during VM creation, select Type 1, not Type 2 [UEFI], unless the HP laptop used a UEFI motherboard)_, and set that SSD as the drive to boot from. _(You'll also want to access it via RDP, not via the window viewer inside Hyper-V, which is done by creating an internal switch [network adapter] in Hyper-V for Win11, connecting the same switch in the VM config options,  and connecting via RDP to the IP of the Windows 7 VM for that switch)_

Comment: Thanks. So I am wanting to boot up as usual to my new windows 10,  but have that old win 7 as a VM that I can refer to as and when needed?

Comment: Right - install Hyper-V via `WinKey`+`R` > `OptionalFeatures` > tick Hyper-V > You may need to reboot. When you want to use the old drive within the VM, you'll need to Offline it first via Disk Management [`DiskMgmt.msc`]. In Hyper-V, create a new VM and select for it to make a new Dynamic Disk at the default value, and once you offline the drive, go into the VM settings, select the _Hard Drive_ and change it to _Physical hard disk_, selecting the offline drive, save it, and boot the VM. Hyper-V VM settings [example](https://i.imgur.com/VaPpWRC.png)

Answer (score -1):

Your question sound more like a to-do list, so yes, go ahead an do it.
If the question is if it is possible to [access raw disks or physical partitions form a VM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/adv-storage-config.html) the answer is yes as well.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment in its current form